# How to add "+91" and remove "+91" in edit text in android?

Tags: android

I have an activity in which I have mobile edit text what I want when user enter mobile number I want to add "+91" before number and when user delete full number I want to delete "+91" also .How can I do that

```
TextWatcher m_MobileWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if (!s.toString().contains("+91")) {
            m_InputMobie.setText("+91" + s.toString());
            Selection.setSelection(m_InputMobie.getText(), m_InputMobie.getText().length());
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: @jankigadhiya this one is different

Comment: i thought if he want to add +91 and then remove it.. this `+91` will become unchangeable.. As per my understanding..!! @NiranjPatel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try below code this is working fine, I have checked.

```
TextWatcher m_MobileWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            String text_value = m_InputMobie.getText().toString().trim();
            if(text_value.equalsIgnoreCase("+91"))
            {
                m_InputMobie.setText("");
            }else
            {
                if(!text_value.startsWith("+91") && text_value.length()>0) {
                    m_InputMobie.setText("+91" + s.toString());
                    Selection.setSelection(m_InputMobie.getText(), m_InputMobie.getText().length());
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    };
```

Comment: Please explain what does  ' Selection.setSelection(mMobileNumber.getText(), mMobileNumber.getText().length()); ' do and why its necessary here?..Thanks